# Tensorflow target integer to binary classification

Tags: binary, tensorflow, integer, label, classification

### Question:

Is it possible to manipulate data loaded from tfrecords inside a Tensorflow graph?

### Details:

I am trying to do a binary classification {1, 0} from an integer target label.

Integer values are discrete in the the domain {0, 1, 2, 4, sys.maxsize}.

What I want is to give me 1 if label is 4 or 0 otherwise. Is that possible without re-encoding the dataset?

I am using `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` to compute logits, which of course doesn't work with the above integer.

/ Thank you, 
Fred

Comment: It can be done using a simple loop and comparison with 5. Where does it involve tensorflow?

Comment: True. I was wondering if it can be done inside the Tensorflow graph, without working with the data at all, such as with tensorflow.cond() or similar. Thanks

Comment: Clarified the question. Ended up reencoding the data to just have 1/0 target labels for now.